# Exclusion pattern for CleanDirectory in cake

Tags: .net, cakebuild

How can I create an exclusion pattern within CleanDirectory so that one specific file in that folder does not get deleted?

This is my current code but it wipes the entire folder.

```
var myPath = GetDirectories("/folder").First();
CleanDirectory(myPath);
```

Does it have a facility for that I might be missing? I could not fid one:
https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.IO/DirectoryAliases/36068142

Comment: `GetDirectories("/folder").Where(i => i.FullPath != "something").First()`?